# How to revert to full screen resolution, after nvidia drivers broke my system?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, screen

I tried using some nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04. But they prevented my machine from booting, so I went to the console and used this to purge nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

However, I can now only set my screen display to 1600x1200. My monitor supports 1920x1200, but I don't see that option anymore under the screen display settings.

Under additional drivers, I am using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source).

How can I use 1920x1200 resoltion again?

Is this useful?

```
jon@T7500:/etc/X11$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF100GL [Quadro 4000] [10de:06dd] (rev a3)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GF100GL [Quadro 4000] [10de:0780]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be5] (rev a1)
```

In the Screen Display settings, it thinks I have a Built-in Display. But I do not. I have an external monitor.

The top of my /var/log/Xorg.0.log file is below, truncated to fit withing 30000 charaters. The full file is at https://quantitativenotes.wordpress.com/2016/12/23/varlogxorg-0-log/

```
[    31.696] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    31.696] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    31.696] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    31.696] Current Operating System: Linux T7500 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64
[    31.696] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash
[    31.696] Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
[    31.696] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    31.696] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    31.696]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    31.696] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    31.696] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Dec 23 21:36:14 2016
[    31.698] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    31.701] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    31.701] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    31.701] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    31.701] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    31.703] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    31.703] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    31.703] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    31.703] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    31.703] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    31.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    31.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    31.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    31.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    31.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    31.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    31.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    31.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    31.708] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    31.708]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    31.708] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    31.708] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    31.708] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    31.708] (II) Loader magic: 0x557797e01dc0
[    31.708] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    31.708]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    31.708]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    31.708]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    31.708]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    31.709] (++) using VT number 7

[    31.709] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    31.712] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:06dd:10de:0780 rev 163, Mem @ 0xf4000000/33554432, 0xe0000000/134217728, 0xe8000000/67108864, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    31.712] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    31.714] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    31.736] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.736]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    31.736]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    31.736] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    31.736] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    31.736] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    31.736] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    31.736] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    31.736] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    31.736] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    31.736] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    31.736] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    31.736] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    31.736] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    31.736] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    31.736] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    31.737] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    31.740] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.740]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 1.0.12
[    31.740]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.740]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.740] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    31.740] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    31.742] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.742]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[    31.742]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.742]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.742] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    31.742] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    31.743] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.743]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    31.743]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.743]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.743] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    31.743] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    31.744] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.744]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    31.744]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.744]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.744] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    31.744] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    31.744] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    31.744] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    31.744] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    31.744] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    31.744] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    31.744] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    31.744] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    31.744] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    31.744] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    31.744] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    31.744] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    31.744] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.744]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 1.0.12
[    31.744]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.744]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.744] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    31.744] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    31.744] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[    31.744] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    31.744] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    31.744] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.744]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[    31.744]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.744]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.744] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    31.744] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    31.744] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    31.744] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    31.744] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    31.744] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.744]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    31.744]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.744]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.744] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    31.744] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    31.744] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    31.744] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    31.745] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    31.745] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.745]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    31.745]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    31.745]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    31.745] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    31.745] (II) Unloading vesa
[    31.745] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    31.745] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Dec 8 15:52:25 2015 +1000
[    31.745] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    31.745]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    31.745]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    31.745]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    31.745]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    31.745]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    31.745]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    31.745]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    31.745]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    31.745]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    31.745]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    31.745]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    31.745]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    31.745]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    31.745] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    31.745] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    31.745] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    31.878] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:03:00.0: -19
[    32.003] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:03:00.0: -19
[    32.003] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    32.003] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    32.003] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    32.003] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    32.003] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    32.003] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    32.003] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    32.005] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.005]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    32.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    32.005] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    32.005] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    32.005] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.005]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    32.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    32.005] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    32.005] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    32.005] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    32.005] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.005]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    32.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    32.005] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    32.005] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    32.005] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    32.005] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    32.005] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    32.005] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    32.005] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    32.005] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    32.005] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    32.005] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    32.005] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.005] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    32.005] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    32.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    32.006] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.006]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    32.006]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    32.006] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    32.006] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    32.006] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    32.009] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.009]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.009]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    32.009] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    32.010] (II) VESA(0): Bad V_BIOS checksum
[    32.010] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 14336 kB
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 112.0
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: GF100 Board - 10310500
[    32.070] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[    32.183] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    32.183] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    32.183] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[    32.183] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    32.183] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    32.183] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    32.183] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    32.183] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    32.184] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[    32.184] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level 2
[    32.184] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read successfully
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: f015  Serial#: 843989324
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Year: 2009  Week: 47
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Digital Display Input
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 52  vert.: 32
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Default color space is primary color space
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): redX: 0.680 redY: 0.310   greenX: 0.206 greenY: 0.693
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.055   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Supported established timings:
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Supported standard timings:
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): #1: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): #2: hsize: 1920  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 209
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): #3: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): clock: 154.0 MHz   Image Size:  518 x 324 mm
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1968  h_sync_end 2000 h_blank_end 2080 h_border: 0
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): v_active: 1200  v_sync: 1203  v_sync_end 1209 v_blanking: 1235 v_border: 0
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Serial No: F525M9BI2NAL
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Monitor name: DELL U2410
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 81 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): EDID (in hex):
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  00ffffffffffff0010ac15f04c414e32
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  2f13010380342078ee1ec5ae4f34b126
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  0e5054a54b008180a940d100714f0101
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  010101010101283c80a070b023403020
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  360006442100001a000000ff00463532
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  354d394249324e414c0a000000fc0044
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  454c4c2055323431300a2020000000fd
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0):  00384c1e5111000a202020202020001f
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 61461
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    32.226] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):
[    32.228] Mode: 100 (640x400)
[    32.228]    ModeAttributes: 0x3bf
[    32.228]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[    32.228]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[    32.228]    WinGranularity: 64
[    32.228]    WinSize: 64
[    32.228]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[    32.228]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[    32.228]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000798e
[    32.228]    BytesPerScanline: 640
[    32.228]    XResolution: 640
[    32.228]    YResolution: 400
[    32.228]    XCharSize: 8
[    32.228]    YCharSize: 16
[    32.228]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[    32.228]    BitsPerPixel: 8
[    32.228]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[    32.228]    MemoryModel: 4
[    32.228]    BankSize: 0
[    32.228]    NumberOfImages: 14
[    32.228]    RedMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[    32.228]    PhysBasePtr: 0xe9000000
[    32.228]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 640
[    32.228]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 14
[    32.228]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 14
[    32.228]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.228]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.228]    MaxPixelClock: 229500000
[    32.230] Mode: 101 (640x480)
[    32.230]    ModeAttributes: 0x3bf
[    32.230]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[    32.230]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[    32.230]    WinGranularity: 64
[    32.230]    WinSize: 64
[    32.230]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[    32.230]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[    32.230]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000798e
[    32.230]    BytesPerScanline: 640
[    32.230]    XResolution: 640
[    32.230]    YResolution: 480
[    32.230]    XCharSize: 8
[    32.230]    YCharSize: 16
[    32.230]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[    32.230]    BitsPerPixel: 8
[    32.230]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[    32.230]    MemoryModel: 4
[    32.230]    BankSize: 0
[    32.230]    NumberOfImages: 10
[    32.230]    RedMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[    32.230]    PhysBasePtr: 0xe9000000
[    32.230]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 640
[    32.230]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 10
[    32.230]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 10
[    32.230]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.230]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.230]    MaxPixelClock: 229500000
[    32.232] Mode: 102 (800x600)
[    32.232]    ModeAttributes: 0x33f
[    32.232]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[    32.232]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[    32.232]    WinGranularity: 64
[    32.232]    WinSize: 64
[    32.232]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[    32.232]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[    32.232]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000798e
[    32.232]    BytesPerScanline: 100
[    32.232]    XResolution: 800
[    32.232]    YResolution: 600
[    32.232]    XCharSize: 8
[    32.232]    YCharSize: 16
[    32.232]    NumberOfPlanes: 4
[    32.232]    BitsPerPixel: 4
[    32.232]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[    32.232]    MemoryModel: 3
[    32.232]    BankSize: 0
[    32.232]    NumberOfImages: 2
[    32.232]    RedMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[    32.232]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[    32.232]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 100
[    32.232]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 2
[    32.232]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 2
[    32.232]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.232]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.232]    MaxPixelClock: 108500000
[    32.234] Mode: 103 (800x600)
[    32.234]    ModeAttributes: 0x3bf
[    32.234]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[    32.234]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[    32.234]    WinGranularity: 64
[    32.234]    WinSize: 64
[    32.234]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[    32.234]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[    32.234]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000798e
[    32.234]    BytesPerScanline: 800
[    32.234]    XResolution: 800
[    32.234]    YResolution: 600
[    32.234]    XCharSize: 8
[    32.234]    YCharSize: 16
[    32.234]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[    32.234]    BitsPerPixel: 8
[    32.234]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[    32.234]    MemoryModel: 4
[    32.234]    BankSize: 0
[    32.234]    NumberOfImages: 6
[    32.234]    RedMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[    32.234]    PhysBasePtr: 0xe9000000
[    32.234]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 800
[    32.234]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 6
[    32.234]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 6
[    32.234]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.234]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.234]    MaxPixelClock: 229500000
[    32.235] Mode: 104 (1024x768)
[    32.235]    ModeAttributes: 0x33f
[    32.235]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[    32.235]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[    32.235]    WinGranularity: 64
[    32.235]    WinSize: 64
[    32.235]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[    32.235]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[    32.235]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc000798e
[    32.235]    BytesPerScanline: 128
[    32.235]    XResolution: 1024
[    32.235]    YResolution: 768
[    32.235]    XCharSize: 8
[    32.235]    YCharSize: 16
[    32.235]    NumberOfPlanes: 4
[    32.235]    BitsPerPixel: 4
[    32.235]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[    32.235]    MemoryModel: 3
[    32.235]    BankSize: 0
[    32.235]    NumberOfImages: 1
[    32.235]    RedMaskSize: 0
[    32.235]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.235]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.235]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.235]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.235]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.236]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[    32.236]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[    32.236]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 128
[    32.236]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 1
[    32.236]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 1
[    32.236]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[    32.236]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[    32.236]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[    32.236]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[    32.236]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[    32.236]    MaxPixelClock: 108500000
```

EDIT: Update...

I managed to fix this problem by going to the NVidia website directly, downloading the driver for my graphics card, and installing it. In this case, I downloaded a file called NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run and installed it.

Unfortunately, I have still ended up with a problem when the machine alternately boots successfully, and freezes when asking me to unencrypt my hard disk, which I have asked as a question here: [Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Alternates Between Freezing and Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864257/ubuntu-16-04-boot-alternates-between-freezing-and-working)

Comment: If I use a live boot USB, I get the full screen resolution. Can I copy some setup from that? It says I have a Dell 24" monitor, whereas my broken Ubuntu says I have a built-in display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to reinstall Ubuntu and follow these instructions:

https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with the nvidia drivers before. The open source drivers work better for me. Reboot into the multi user mode target and pass --uninstall to the installer package to uninstall the driver. Upon reboot you should be able to use all your old resolutions.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I'm afraid that I'm too inexperienced to understand your explanation. Please could you elaborate. Thank you!

Comment: P.S. Do you know why it might be incorrectly detecting my external Dell monitor as a built-in display?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be detecting the external monitor incorrectly. I'm mobile right now. When I get to a computer I will type out a more concise response for you unless someone else beats me to it  :)